# How to use ajax tabcontainer in formview?

Tags: ajax, formview, tabcontainer

How to add a tabcontainer in a formview template? I am sure i have a scriptmanager inside the page. but it keep compliaint "A ScriptManager is required on page to use ASP.NET AJAX Script Components. I have also tried move the ScriptManager inside the itemTemplate but same error.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are not using the ToolkitScriptManager?

It's required for Ajax Toolkit components.